# Copying directories unrelated file names

Tags: bash, cp, for

I'm trying to copy directories of data sets that pertain to the a certain case but the data sets are currently stored in different directories and with different (non consecutive) numbered file.

e.g. I have a case file `case_directory/006` and I want to copy and create `case_directory/006/MRS` from where that case's `MRS` directory is currently stored in `data_directory/150/MRS`. The next case would be `case_directory/010` and for that I would want to copy `data_directory/155/MRS` - just to illustrate there is really no relation between the numbering systems. I have about 120 of such case directories so would be great to automate the copying process from the matching data directory! :-/

Can I automate this using the `for`  and `cat` commands and text files containing lists where the matching numbers are on the same row in each text file? can you use more than 1 variable with `for` or do I need to use a more complicated script?

Comment: Use a `while`/`read` loop: `while read num1 num2; do cp -R case_directory/$num1/MRS data_directory/$num2; done < file_with_matching_nums` instead of a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data file looks like this

```
006 150
010 155
...
```

You can use a simple loop to read the source and destination numbers

```
while read ncase ndata
do
    cp -a case_directory/$ncase/MRS data_directory/$ndata/
done < casedatafile
```

Comment: thank you so much @muru and @roaima - worked a treat! Will be using `while read` until I'm blue in the face now!

Comment: There are [many reasons](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) _not_ to use `while read` without serious pause for thought. Here, though, it's a sufficient solution.